# Converting from xlsx to mht error: Microsoft Office Excel: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a VBScript which converts from xlsx to mht using Excel 2007. Here is the VBScript

```
' This script takes two parameters
' $1: XLSX Filename (should be full path if possible, with ending)
' $2: MHT Filename (should be full path if possible, with ending)

' Constant definitions
Const xlWebArchive = 45

' Store the arguments in a variable:
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
XLSX_Filename = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
MHT_Filename = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)

Wscript.Echo "XLSX Filename: " & XLSX_Filename
Wscript.Echo "MHT Filename: " & MHT_Filename

' Create an instance of Excel and open the workbook...
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open XLSX_Filename

' Save the workbook as an MHTML page...
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs MHT_Filename, xlWebArchive

' Close Excel...
objExcel.Quit
```

But using that method, I am getting the error:

```
xlsx_to_mht.vbs(24, 1) Microsoft Office Excel: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed
```

which is the line

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs MHT_Filename, xlWebArchive
```

So why that error?

**EDIT: Example output of the script**

```
# converting from xlsx to mht
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

XLSX Filename: C:\path\to\project\ThirdPartyLicense.xlsx
MHT Filename: C:\path\to\project\ThirdPartyLicense.mht
C:\path\to\vbscript\xlsx_to_mht_conv\xlsx_to_mht.vbs(24, 1) Microsoft Office Excel: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed
```

Comment: *The two files exist* - I may be reading this wrong, but if the MHT file already exists the `Workbook.SaveAs` will not overwrite it automatically. You will have to delete the existing MHT files before saving it again.

Comment: You were right. The MHT file does not exist :D.

Comment: just curious, what is the value of `MHT_Filename` when you try to save it?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I edited the question with the output of the script when running.

Comment: I just ran this with the exact script and arguments you provided and it worked smoothly. I have a few questions ... Is that the exact path you are using or is just a test path? Is there something in the file that would make it not be able to convert to HTML without some kind of compatibility warning (For example, what happens if you try it to save as an MHT file manually?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution (for my case). I tried, like Scott Holtzman suggested, open that file in Excel manually and see what Excel does. Excel was not activated. I activated it. The error disappeared.